# Why JavaScript console prints inconsistent value?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="alpha"  value="ccc">
    </div>
    
    <script>
        
        console.log(btn.attributes.getNamedItem("onclick")) ;
        console.log(btn.attributes.getNamedItem("onclick").value) ;

        btn.attributes.getNamedItem("onclick").value = "beta()";
        function beta(){
            alert(`alpha changed to beta`);
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

About

`console.log(btn.attributes.getNamedItem("onclick"));`

This line prints **onclick="beta()"**,

`console.log(btn.attributes.getNamedItem("onclick").value);` 
This line prints **alpha**

Above two lines are identically written before the overwriting line
`btn.attributes.getNamedItem("onclick").value = "beta()";`

I think these two console.log() line should operate in same way

```
        console.log(btn.attributes.getNamedItem("onclick")) ;
        console.log(btn.attributes.getNamedItem("onclick").value) ;
```

Only difference is just second one prints first one's **.value**
But where these different result derived from?

Comment: It must be that this isn't a valid way of writing to the DOM.  Use setAttribute instead - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: huh. interestingly enough, in Firefox (as opposed to Chrome) it prints the alpha twice, as expected.

Comment: I'd recommend using `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` for consistency. `console.log(btn.getAttribute('onclick'));
btn.attributes.getNamedItem("onclick").value = "beta()";
console.log(btn.getAttribute('onclick'));` works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, but i want to know why this problem happens because i'm afraid to meet this simillar problems in the future

Comment: It happens because what you're attempting is not safe javascript - it will either yield the wrong result, or inconsistent results. Either way, stick to best practices - hence the recommendations

Comment: `btn.attributes.getNamedItem("onclick")` in firefox outputs the full https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap/getNamedItem object, not just `onclick="beta()"`. This seems to work as expected though: `console.log(btn.attributes.getNamedItem("onclick").value) ;
btn.attributes.getNamedItem("onclick").value = "beta()";
console.log(btn.attributes.getNamedItem("onclick").value) ;` so it looks like it depends on which browser you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that by logging `onclick`, you are logging the **event object** and with `onclick.value` you are logging the **event handling callback reference** (alpha).

Now, you are accessing the element in JavaScript via its `id` attribute directly, rather than with a DOM querying technique. When you give an element an `id`, it becomes a Global property of the `window` object and if you access it solely by the `id`, you are accessing a `window` property, which holds a reference to an object. `window` is not part of the DOM and therefore not standard.

However, if you access the element via `document.querySelector()`, which is a DOM querying method, you get back a DOM object and will see standard DOM properties.

**The use of `getNamedItem()`, `setAttribute()`, and `getAttribute()` is not needed. Simply accessing the property directly will give you access to that data (i.e. `btn.onclick = foo()`).**

Also, the use of event properties (like `onclick`) is discouraged. This is an older way of setting up events, but it's not as robust as the modern, standard of `.addEventListener()`, which is what you should be using.

Here's an example of the standards-based way of interacting with DOM elements. The following is standards-based code and will yield consistent results in all modern clients.

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <!-- Notice that the id and onclick attributes have been removed. -->
        <input type="button" value="ccc">
    </div>
    
    <script>
        // Instead of direct referencing elements via their id attribute,
        // use a standard DOM querying method to get a DOM element reference
        const btn = document.querySelector("input[type='button']");
        
        // Instead of wiring up elements to events in HTML with event attributes,
        // use the modern standard of .addEventListener() which allows for
        // multiple event handlers for any given event.
        btn.addEventListener("click", alpha);
        btn.addEventListener("click", beta);
        
        function alpha(event){
            // To access details about a DOM element, just access the 
            // property directly. In this event callback function, the 
            // object that fired the event can be referenced via its DOM
            // reference (btn), the event target (event.target), or the object
            // that caused the event callback to be called (this).
            console.log("Hello from alpha");
            console.log("You clicked: ", event.target);
            console.log("The element is a: ", this.nodeName);
            console.log("...with a type of: ", btn.type);
            console.log("...with a value of: " + event.target.value);
            console.log("The event being handled is: ", event.type);
            console.log("And the event object itself is: ", event);
        }
        function beta(){
            console.log("Hello from beta");
        }

    </script>
</body>
```